# Get the number of rows in a JavaFX GridPane?

Tags: java, layout, javafx, javafx-2, pane

I initialized a GridPane through SceneBuilder and inside the controller I want to conditionally add a row to the GridPane. I do not want to store an int for how many rows I initialized, I want to be able to get the number of rows from the GridPane object. Is that possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hej j will, try this method:

```
private int getRowCount(GridPane pane) {
        int numRows = pane.getRowConstraints().size();
        for (int i = 0; i < pane.getChildren().size(); i++) {
            Node child = pane.getChildren().get(i);
            if (child.isManaged()) {
                Integer rowIndex = GridPane.getRowIndex(child);
                if(rowIndex != null){
                    numRows = Math.max(numRows,rowIndex+1);
                }
            }
        }
        return numRows;
    }
```

This worked for me.

Patrick

Comment: Isn't rowIndex and rowEnd same numbers? Both are obtained with GridPane.getRowIndex(child).

Comment: Yeah this doesn't work when I prorammatically add rows to a gridpane it still shows the initial row count, so it has issues

Comment: I could have a valid GridPane with a non-empty set of rows, then call getRowConstraints() which is a list, call clear() to clear this list to remove all constraints and then when I call your getRowCount() get a return value of 0 even though the grid still has the same number of rows.

Answer (score 7):

In my case I used Java Reflections ( GridPane.java has private method *getNumberOfRows()* ):

```
Method method = gridPane.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getNumberOfRows");
method.setAccessible(true);
Integer rows = (Integer) method.invoke(gridPane);
```

Comment: this works after I have added rows in code otherwise all I get is the initial allocation, which is dumb, poor form from the designers of the GridPane class

Answer (score 3):

With java 9, you can do this:

```
myGridPane.getRowCount();
```

Comment: I believe this returns the row index of the element with the largest row index, so if you have gaps between rows, this doesn't return the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
GridPane.getRowConstraints().size()
```